# Loop over list of R objects and change each object

Tags: r, loops, object

I want to make a list of objects of a particular class in R, go through the list, and change each object according to some criterion. For example:

```
Duck <- function(grade,cap) {
  res <- structure(list(grade=grade,cap=cap),class="Duck")
  return(res)
}

Kwik <- Duck(5,0)
Kwek <- Duck(7,0)
Kwak <- Duck(9,0)

# Select all Ducks from the workspace
AllDucks <- Filter( function(x) 'Duck' %in% class( get(x) ), ls() )

# Give each Duck with a grade higher than 5 a cap (i.e. cap is set to 1)
for(i in 1:length(AllDucks)) {
  if(get(AllDucks[i])$grade > 5) {
    get(AllDucks[i])$cap <- 1
  }
}
```

The expression `get(AllDucks[i])$cap <- 1` gives the error message

```
Error in get(AllDucks[i])$cap <- 1 : could not find function "get<-"
```

How can I pick an object from a list of objects and change some of its attributes?

Comment: The assignment operator `<-` cannot be applied on `get()`, it's not defined. One possible solution is to replace `get(AllDucks[i])$cap <- 1` by `eval(parse(text=paste(AllDucks[i], "$cap <- 1", sep = "")))`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't your ducks swim nicely in a pond? You should give them a nice habitat to begin with, but you can also catch them from the wild:

```
pond <- mget(AllDucks)
pond <- lapply(pond, function(x) {
  if (x$grade > 5) x$cap <- 1
  x
})

pond$Kwek
# $grade
# [1] 7
# 
# $cap
# [1] 1
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "Duck"
```

Comment: Does the trick - almost! How do I get the values of `pond$Kwek` back into `Kwek`?

Comment: You could use `list2env`. But my point was that you shouldn't do that. It's far better to keep them in the list and there is really no good reason to put them in the `.GlobalEnv`.

Answer (score 0):

To reassign into the current environment, you could do

```
mapply(assign, AllDucks, lapply(mget(AllDucks), function(x) {x$cap<-1; x}), 
    MoreArgs =list(envir = environment()))
```